# Google Maps - How to locate a marker in a markers array?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How can I check if a google map marker is already inside an array of markers?
Even after this `markersArray.push(marker);` the condition `(marker in markersArray)` is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `(marker in markersArray)` is wrong since `in` doesn't look for elements in the array.
It looks for properties.

The way it worked for me was

```
for (var i=0; i<markersArray.length; i++) {
    if (markersArray[i].getPosition().equals(marker.getPosition())) {
...
```

This works as long as what you need compared is only the coordinates of the markers.
We use here the LatLng class' .equals operator.

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate through the array to check for the marker.

```
for (var i=0; i<markersArray.length; i++) {
  if (markersArray[i] === marker) {
     //doSomething...
     break;
     }
  }
```

Comment: @rob, so if I have, say, a 1000 markers on the map and I'm panning the map just a little bit so all the markers should still appear, and I've been told not to remove and add again markers but to check first if they're already there, so that would mean that for each of the 1000 markers I will have to averagely go through half of the array. That could lead to 500,000 checks, in worst case scenario. Wouldn't it be less consuming to just remove all 1000 markers and then add them back?

Comment: I doubt it would be better to remove and add them back, as there is a fair amount of overhead to that process.  One option, if you have a performance problem, would be to store your markers separately in a lookup table, so you don't actually have to iterate.  If you have any unique identifier on each marker, you can use that as the member name in an object.  There are various other means you could use to keep track of them, since you are presumably creating, adding and remove these markers yourself.

Comment: @Ash: do you add markers to the visible region and hide those that are in the invisible region when the map is panned?

Comment: @Salman A, no. When the map has finished panning or zooming (idle event) I get the lat,lng of the viewport's bounds and with an ajax call I get from the db only the coordinates which are in this viewport's bounds.

Comment: @Ash... exactly as I thought. In that case rob's comment (the one with a +1) would be my answer. You're probably pulling lat/lng from DB and there's probably a PK associated with that lat/lng. All you need to do is (i) `markersArray = {}` (ii) instead of push, do a `markersArray['x_' + id] = marker;` -- this creates a property e.g. `markersArray.x_1234` (iii) to check if it exists `if(typeof markersArray['x_' + id] == 'undefined')`. Accessing properties of an object is probably a whole lot faster than iterating an array with 1000+ elements.

Comment: @Salman A, I'm not sure I understand - do you mean that a new marker will enter the array as a property instead of an array organ? So if I have a 1000 markers returned from the DB the array will get 1000 properties but no regular elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            icon:icon,
                            position: position, 
                            map: map
                        });
```

Markers have own ID. You can get this ID by

```
var marker_id = marker.__gm_id;
```

and then get marker on map

```
map.Hb.qa[marker_id];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
markersArray.indexOf(marker) > -1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can use it in my case since I have to create an instance of marker to be able to compare it but if I create it than that instance can't really be in the array. I think I have to use the `===` operator.